# javascript - difference between two Labels

Tags: javascript

I have one question related to Javascript Validation:

How could I find the difference(the characters which are available in first label but not are in second label) between two Labels ?

Thanks - see the code below:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="44%" align="right">Label 1</td>
    <td width="56%"><input type="text" value="ABCD" /></td>
    <td width="56%" style="color:#C00;">Note</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Label 2</td>
    <td><input  type="text" value="AEBHL" /></td>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top">I want to show the difference of Label 1 and Label 2 in Diffrence's input. How could I find the difference?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Difference</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="EHL" style="border:1px solid #C00;" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show some JS code and HTML. And also where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text of the first label.

Get the text of the second label.

Compute the difference between the two labels.
Assign the difference to the difference row.

> You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Anton87/RDvJf/

```
var label1 = jQuery("table tr:eq(0) input").val(),
    label2 = jQuery("table tr:eq(1) input").val(),
    diff2 = difference(label2, label1);

jQuery("table tr:eq(2) input").val(diff2);

function difference(label1, label2) {   
   var difference = [];

   for (var i = 0, max = label1.length; i < max; i++) {
      if (label2.indexOf(label1[i]) === -1) {
        difference.push(label1[i]);
      }
   }

   return difference;
}
```